# Composable that reacts to parent's focus state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, focus

I am working on Android TV app with use of Jetpack Compose. I wanted to create a reusable Composable Icon that animates when focus state changes. I've managed to get something that reacts to focus changes on it and it works fine.

```
@Composable
fun MyIcon(
    iconState: IconState,
    contentDescription: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {},
) {
...
Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                val hasFocus = focusState.hasFocus
                ...
            }
            .clickable { onClick() },
    ) {
    ...
```

Now I've put this Icon inside of a button and I'd like it to animate when Button is focused, but looks like focus state isn't transferred to the children of the Button.
I've tried using focusRequester in such a way:

```
        val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
        Button(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.onFocusChanged {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    focusRequester.requestFocus()
                }
            },
        ) {
            MyIcon(
                iconState = iconState,
                contentDescription = "",
                onClick = { ... },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .size(96.dp),
            )
            Text(text = "")
        }
```

and it animates the icon, but not entire button is being focused - you can see the gray area is not on entire button. How can I make it work?

[image: focused icon inside of a button]

I was thinking about having focused state passed to the icon instead and setting this state in button's onFocusChanged modifier. In case focus state is set to null, I could still set up `onFocusChanged` modifier in my Icon, making it generic and reusable alone:

```
        var buttonFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Button(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.onFocusChanged {
                buttonFocus = it.isFocused
            },
        ) {
            MyIcon(
                iconState = iconState,
                contentDescription = "",
                hasFocus = buttonFocus,
                onClick = { ... },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(96.dp),
            )
            Text(text = "")
        }
```

But can it be done better?